# Django registration email never arrives

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using django [registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) to handle um... registration on a site I'm building.  I'm running on ubuntu and I've installed postfix and dovecot and maybe some other email apps that I don't fully understand (I used [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/postfix.html) instructions).

So now I'm pretty sure the postfix server is working.  On the system shell I can do:

```
$ mail -s 'test' pete@example.com
```

and I get an email 30 nano seconds later.  Similarly, in the django shell I can issue:

```
>>> send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'service@example.com',['pete@example.com'],fail_silently=False)
```

and I get another email.  But, the registration app still never seems to get an email out.  I'm at a loss for where to start debugging this, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

PS: i've completed all the django registration required templates

Comment: Does the mail show up in your terminal if you setup a debugging server with python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802189/django-errno-111-connection-refused/5802348#5802348

Comment: What all django-registration settings have you added to settings.py? ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS is required.

Comment: @arie--thanks for that tip, I didn't know about the debugging server.  This is incredibly bizarre, but I set the django email port to 1025 for debug but now I'm actually getting the emails (which shouldn't happen because they should go to stdout).  Anyways, if your post you comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept.  @tarkeshwar yep I've got the ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS set...

Comment: hey smokefoot, i turned my comment into an answer. did you get the problem tracked further down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if you application sends the mail correctly using python's [DebuggingServer](http://docs.python.org/library/smtpd.html#debuggingserver-objects)? See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802189/django-errno-111-connection-refused/5802348#5802348) for some details.
Alternatively you could try Django's [ConsoleBackend](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/?from=olddocs#console-backend) for debugging the sending of mails.

Additionally you could try sending mails [using your mail provider](http://snipplr.com/view/26605/django-send-email-through-gmail/).