# NotImplementedError in django-registration when registering a user

Tags: python, django, django-registration, user-profile

I have a django app and trying to use `django-registration` app in it. And below are my settings and codes

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'south',
    'registration',
    'user_profile',
 )

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "user_profile.UserProfile"
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

project **urls.py** file

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('user_profile.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
 )
```

**user_profile urls.py** file

```
from registration.views import RegistrationView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(),
        {'backend': 'user_profile.backends.RegistrationBackend'},
        name='registration_register'),
)
```

**user_profile.backends.py** file

```
from .forms import RegistrationForm
from user_profile.models import UserProfile
from registration.views import RegistrationView

class RegistrationBackend(RegistrationView):
    def get_form_class(self, request)
        return RegistrationForm

    def register(self, request, **kwargs):
        kwargs["username"] = kwargs["email"]
        user = super(RegistrationBackend, self).register(request, **kwargs)
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)
        return user
```

So from the above code when the user hits the url `localhost:8000/accounts/register`
a registration form will be displayed, and after entering all the fields(`username,email, password, password`) and clicked on **register** button i am getting the below `NotImplementedError`

```
NotImplementedError at /accounts/register/
No exception supplied
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/register/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: NotImplementedError
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback:
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py" in dispatch
  79.         return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  86.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py" in post
  35.             return self.form_valid(request, form)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py" in form_valid
  82.         new_user = self.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py" in register
  109.         raise NotImplementedError

Exception Type: NotImplementedError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value:
```

can anyone know how to avoid this `NotImplementedError`, actually according to the original view at `python2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py` , the `register` method is

```
def register(self, request, **cleaned_data):
    """
    Implement user-registration logic here. Access to both the
    request and the full cleaned_data of the registration form is
    available here.

    """
    raise NotImplementedError
```

But i am providing the backend class to use for registering the user in my url as  {`'backend': 'user_profile.backends.RegistrationBackend'},` but still it is not overriding and displaying the origin functional error.

So what i am doing wrong in the above scenario and how to fix and make the user save ?

**Edit**

After modifying code as indicated by `Paco`

when tried to register the user i got below error

```
error at /accounts/register/
[Errno 111] Connection refused
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/register/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: error
Exception Value:    
[Errno 111] Connection refused
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback:
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py" in dispatch
  79.         return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  86.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py" in post
  35.             return self.form_valid(request, form)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py" in form_valid
  82.         new_user = self.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/backends/default/views.py" in register
  80.                                                                     password, site)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  223.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/models.py" in create_inactive_user
  91.             registration_profile.send_activation_email(site)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/models.py" in send_activation_email
  270.         self.user.email_user(subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL)
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in email_user
  422.         send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py" in send_mail
  62.                         connection=connection).send()
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
  255.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in send_messages
  88.             new_conn_created = self.open()
File "/home/user/proj/combined/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in open
  49.                                            local_hostname=DNS_NAME.get_fqdn())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py" in __init__
  249.             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py" in connect
  309.         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py" in _get_socket
  284.         return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py" in create_connection
  571.         raise err

Exception Type: error at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 5):

My similar problem solved by

```
from registration.backends.model_activation.views import RegistrationView
```

instead of

```
from registration.views import RegistrationView
```

in `urls.py`
(django 1.9)

Comment: This is an issue in django 1.11 if you want to import RegistrationView implement RegistrationFormUniqueEmail like this: url(r'^accounts/register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationFormUniqueEmail), name='registration_register'),

Comment: Fixed it for me too! I'm using Django 3.1.  I used `from django_registration.backends.activation.views import RegistrationView` . There's also  `from django_registration.backends.one_step.views import RegistrationView`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to inherit from a method that raises NotImplementedError. Try this instead.

```
def register(self, request, **kwargs):
    UserProfile.objects.create(**kwargs)
    return user
```

Otherwise, you inheriting the raise as well.

Your edit is a different issue.

Have a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802189/django-errno-111-connection-refused). It is due to the send_mail function. I quote:

> For debugging purposes you could setup a local smtpserver with this
>   command:
>
> python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
>
> and adjust your mail settings accordingly:
>
> EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
>   EMAIL_PORT = 1025
>
> This is documented here: Testing e-mail sending

Comment: k when i used above code its displaying `[Errno 111] Connection refused' see my edited question above

Comment: In the example above, where `user` comes from in the method?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `[Errno 111] Connection refused', you must have a mail server to sen thje email (Aka postfix or sendmail). Start your mail server !