# sentry sent the email get error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, django, email, ubuntu

I install the sentry on my server with the Document，one-step，one-step，use my own postgresql，I just change the Database config
Finally,I invite myself by sent email,get this problem

[image: the error information]

Comment: What is your email settings? Does it work via desktop email client?

Comment: default,I ditn't change it

Comment: so, the default smtp server is a "localhost", do you have an email server on the same machine, where you run django? Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802189/django-errno-111-connection-refused

Comment: No,this machine is new,I just install ubuntu and some package which are dependencies for sentry

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities
one：have some error in your config file，for instance your email password or smtp  server and so on 
two: you don't install smtp software，like postfix,sendmail and so on,and smtp is localhost in your config file